# Problems installing django-observer package

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip

Hello I am trying to install django-observer for python3 on my Win10 PC but I keep getting following error message:

```
Collecting django-observer
  Using cached django-observer-0.4.3.tar.gz (7.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: django>=1.2 in c:\users\luca dieling\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from django-observer) (3.1.4)
Collecting distribute
  Using cached distribute-0.7.3.zip (145 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Luca Dieling\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k757dx1_\\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Luca Dieling\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-k757dx1_\\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-00os3tdp'
         cwd: C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k757dx1_\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k757dx1_\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k757dx1_\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k757dx1_\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\setuptools\dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k757dx1_\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\setuptools\command\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k757dx1_\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\setuptools\command\install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "C:\Users\Luca Dieling\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k757dx1_\distribute_c11e8be23eda49c7809d38d8e88b222e\pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am running the command pip install django-observer

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `django-observer` package hasn't been maintained for a long time. The [github repository](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-observer) states it works on Python 3 version 3.2 and 3.3 though. So you might have luck setting up a virtualenv with python 3.2 or 3.3 and working from there.

The package appears to have done work similar to that of Django Signals. You can read up on them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/). Signals are an implementation of the Observer pattern.

Just FYI, I tried installing the package too and got the same error on my MacOS machine. This is why I suggest switching to Signals.